# Unity 5 Animation attaching

Tags: javascript, animation, unity

I have created the walking and idle animation for my fps player. I've added a JavaScript script to access it, but when I run it and press button(w), it stops and says that the animation is not attached to the object.

When I drag the walking/idle animation and drop to that object, it creates an animation controller. Again I run it, still same error. I can't find where to attach the animation

Here's my script:

```
function Update () 
{
  if(Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
  {
    GetComponent.<Animation>().Play("walk_anim2", PlayMode.StopAll);
  }
  if(Input.GetKeyUp("w"))
  {
    GetComponent.<Animation>().Play("idle_anim2", PlayMode.StopAll);
  }
}
```

Where do I need to attach the animation?

[image]

Comment: Can you screencap the hierarchy where the relevant GameObject is and whatever the inspector is showing with this player selected?

Comment: Is the animation controller that you are attaching the one with the animations in it? I have had this issue before when adding an animation controller it just creates an empty on instead. If that is the case simply copy your animations into that controller that is attached to your game object.

Comment: i've added the screenshot.... i can't understand.. hlp pls !!!

Comment: You have an `Animator` component attached but your script is asking for an `Animation` component. These are two different things.

Comment: i've added the animation component too. but, that was also not working. anyway,  what exactly i have to do right now?

Answer (score 2):

You are using an `Animator` component but you are referencing `Animation` in your script. You can see in the error it says `MissingComponent`. You should use `Animator` component.

Here is the link for relevant API page: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html